# Why is $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ not an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, real-numbers, integers

This is an embarrassing question which might seem elementary and possibly silly, but its suddenly confusing me. Clearly I'm missing something very obvious.

Take the structure $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$. It is an abelian group under addition. As for an $\mathbb{R}$-action on it, that too can be defined in a natural way: for $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x + \mathbb{Z} \in \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$,
$$a(x+\mathbb{Z})=ax + \mathbb{Z}$$
This action distributes over the abelian group addition, the scalar action is compatible with the field multiplication, and the multiplicative identity of $\mathbb{R}$ fixes all elements. It seems to satisfy all the axioms of a vector space.

> So shouldn't this make $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space?

But clearly this isn't correct. So what am I missing here?

Comment: The action is not well defined. For example, if $x+\mathbb{Z}=y+\mathbb{Z}$, it is not true that $\pi x + \mathbb{Z}=\pi y + \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @JohnnyElCurvas Why are you answering the question in the comment section?

Comment: Also, if $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ were a vector space with that structure, then $q\colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ given by $q(x)=x+\mathbb{Z}$ would be linear, making $\mathbb{Z}=\ker q$ a vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}$...

Comment: Ooh, brain freeze. Thanks!

Comment: @Arthur I felt like what I said is too short for an answer.

Comment: @BharatRam no problem!

Comment: @Johnny El Curvas: Your first comment was most helpful. I do know many reasons why the result is incorrect, but just wanted to understand why this doesn't fit in with the vector space axioms.

Comment: @JohnnyElCurvas As long as it's over 30 characters, and addresses the question, that's all you need. The comment box explicitly tells you not to do it there.

Comment: @Arthur: Considering this turned out trivial and embarassing as I predicted, do you think I should just delete this question instead of hogging the space?

Comment: @Arthur sorry, my bad. At least I'll elaborate more on what I said in an answer.

Comment: @BharatRam I'd leave the question up and accept the answer below.

Comment: @BharatRam Don't be embarrassed and don't delete this question, asking "easy" questions is the best thing you can do to learn mathematics. Every good mathematician asks thousands of "stupid questions".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the action of $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ is not well defined.

Suppose $x+\mathbb{Z}=y+\mathbb{Z}$, this means that there exists some $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $y-x=n$. Given some $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$, the equality $\lambda x+\mathbb{Z}=\lambda y+\mathbb{Z}$ means that $\lambda(y-x)=m$ for some $m\in \mathbb{Z}$. In particular $\lambda=m/n$ must be rational (assuming $y\neq x$), which is a contradiction since $\lambda$ is arbitrary.

Comment: Also, don't feel embarassed for these kinds of things. They happen to us all the time! :-)

Comment: A different proof is needed for the "action" of $\mathbb{Q}$ on $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: For the case of $\mathbb{Q}$: $0+\mathbb{Z}=1+\mathbb{Z}$, but $\frac{0}{2}+\mathbb{Z}\neq \frac{1}{2}+\mathbb{Z}$, so the action is not well defined even if we restrict ourselves to the rational numbers.